# Programmatically chosing y-axis limits for plotting functions having asymtotes

Tags: calculus, graphing-functions

Plotting some arbitrary function having a vertical asymptote,
$$
y = \frac{x}{1-x^2}
$$
using WolframAlpha with $x\in[-5,5]$ and $x\in[-100,100]$, results in the following plots:

[image]

Now my question is, what would be a general method for programmatically choosing y-axis limits for displaying functions having vertical asymptotes?

Or more general, for relatively steep functions like $y=10^x$.

Comment: Do you mean, how does Wolfram decide when to stop plotting vertically?

Comment: @FShrike Yes, how does Wolfram decide the y-axis limits